# select count and sum of data for different ranges of another column

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a table with the design below:

SaleDataTbl :

- id
- ColumnA
- ColumnB
- ColumnC

`ColumnA` has different values and i want to group them in 4 ranges: `[0-100) , [100-200), [200-300), [300-400]` and I want the count of rows for each ranges mentioned, and sum of `ColumnB` and `ColumnC` for each ranges. I can do it by multiple queries but Can i do it with only one query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not much more than an aggregation query:

```
select grp, count(*), sum(columnb), sum(columnc)
from (select t.*,
             (case when columnA < 100 then '[000-100)'
                   when columnA < 200 then '[100-200)'
                   when columnA < 300 then '[200-300)'
                   when columnA < 400 then '[300-400)'
              end) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp
order by grp;
```

Notes:

- I doubt you really want inclusive ranges.  Why would "100" show up in two buckets?
- The subquery is not really necessary.  It highlights the definition of the ranges.
- I don't really see a natural way to split this into multiple queries.

Comment: @Peyman.H . . . This is standard SQL and should work in just about any database.